# Unable to receive local notifications Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, notifications

I'm new to Android programming and I'm trying to build my first app. Right now I want to send local notifications. Unfortunately I cannot receive notifications on devices running API 28 and above. I know there is a change in the way notifications are sent since Oreo and I have included code that creates the channel. It seems like if I run the app on a simulator with a lower API (e.g. 19) the notification is received. Also if I copy my code into a new project I receive the notifications, even on a simulator running Android Oreo. What settings in the project could cause notifications not to be received on Android Oreo? (There are no errors in Logcat)

My code for sending the notifications:

```
public static final String CHANNEL_1_ID = "channel1";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    createNotificationChannels();
}

public void setNotif(View view) {
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("hey")
            .setContentText("world")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .build();
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}

private void createNotificationChannels() {
    // if higher than android oreo
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_1_ID, "Channel 1", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel1.setDescription("This is channel 1");

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
    }
}
```

The setNotif method is called by a tap of a button. Again, I'm new to Android programming so any advice would be helpful. Maybe even a different way in which I could diagnose the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add this check in your `setNotif()` method:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)  
  notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(getNotificationChannel(context));
```

`setNotif()` method will be changed like this :

```
public void setNotif(View view) {
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("hey")
            .setContentText("world")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .build();
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(getNotificationChannel(context));
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

And getNotificationChannel() method will look like this:

```
private static NotificationChannel getNotificationChannel(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            return null;
        CharSequence name = context.getString(R.string.app_name);// The user-visible name of the channel.
        int importance = android.app.NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, name, importance);
        notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
        return notificationChannel;
    }
```

Comment: notificationManager does not have a createNotificationChannel method, am I missing something?

Comment: Instead of  `NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);` you can try getting NottificationManager service like this `android.app.NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (android.app.NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`

Comment: it still doesn't work :( what I think is crazy is that if I go in the settings of the simulator (or device) in the notifications section I can see my app in the recently sent pane... also if I tap on the app I can see the notifications channels that I set.

I don't think the channels are the problem...something else is